# Duplicate pattern, different name in included django url

Tags: python, django, url, django-1.7

I'm struggling with this problem in a Django app:
My main app urls file has this two lines:

```
url(r'^root-pattern-1/', include('loan.urls')),
url(r'^root-pattern-2/', include('loan.urls')),
```

And in my loan.urls I have the following two entries:

```
url(r'^search/$', Search.as_view(),
            name='personal-loan-result', kwargs={'loantype': LOAN_TYPE_PERSONAL}),
url(r'^search/$', Search.as_view(loantype=LOAN_TYPE_CREDIT),
            name='creditcard-loan-result', kwargs={'loantype': LOAN_TYPE_CREDIT}),
```

The problem is that when I call `reverse('creditcard-loan-result')` the url seems ok, but it's calling the url named 'personal-loan-result', that is the first entry.
I've been reading a lot and saw in other questions here that the options are including my loan.urls file with empty pattern or changing the order of the url entries.
Is there some other option that I am missing? changing the order will not work in this specific case and I don't like the idea of including the urls with empty pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me why you are including `loan.urls` twice, so apologies if I've misunderstood your question.

```
url(r'^search/$', Search.as_view(),
        name='personal-loan-result', kwargs={'loantype': LOAN_TYPE_PERSONAL}),
url(r'^search/$', Search.as_view(loantype=LOAN_TYPE_CREDIT),
        name='creditcard-loan-result', kwargs={'loantype': LOAN_TYPE_CREDIT}),
```

These are both for the same url, `/search/`. It doesn't matter whether you call `reverse('personal-loan-result')` or `reverse('creditcard-loan-result')`, the url that is displayed in the browser is simply `/search/`, and Django will always use the first url pattern that matches.

If you want to direct results to the second pattern, then you need two different regexes, for example you could use `^search/personal/$` and `^search/credit/$`.

Comment: The two includes are there because are the only two cases where we want to have the loan app urls included, i know a solution could be include loan.urls always (using and empty pattern)
The url displayed in the browser will be `/root-pattern-1/search/` or `/root-pattern-2/search/`